# login to zwave from python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, z-wave

I've been trying to login to the zwave module from python, but so far it hasn't worked. 
So far I've used:

- requests
- twill
- mechanize
- robobrowser

I've noticed that the zwave goes through 'app/views/auth/auth_login.html' to log you in, but I just can't seem to get it.
I hope you guys have any tips on how I (might) login via python :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out I was an idiot. I can access it by going to the website with requests and use the `auth=('login','password')` with it.